# AnsiDialect not available in spring-data-jpa tree

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-jdbc

I'm interested to use an AnsiDialect from spring-data-jdbc to connect to my Oracle database using a proprietary driver. However, this dialect is not present in spring-data-jpa (only contains dialects from hibernate)

Is there a way to do this, or do I need to implement my own dialect?

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, it seem that the equivalent of AnsiDialect is simply org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect. Don't know why I didn't think about this :)